How to Enable LVM full disk encryption on Ubuntu device post OS installation
How to Enable LVM full disk encryption on Ubuntu 22.04 post OS installation
We have existing Ubuntu devices without encryption, plan to onboard to Intune with LVM encryption without reinstalling the OS.
Is there any script or available solution to encrypt the Ubuntu device full drive encryption.
